# Dynamic Json via AJAX to an MVC 3 method

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an jquery AJAX call that passes dynamically constructed Json to a controller method. The problem I am facing is that I am not getting data back when my method is hit... I am trying to use JsonResult at the moment and have tried different collections as well with no luck.  So what I'm wondering is which obect type should I use to receive this parameter that would be generic enough to handle my dynamic Json structure?  I have also test that my Json is valid using http://jsonlint.com/

View code:

$(".saveButton").click(function () {

```
    var jsonObjects = GetValues();

    $.ajax({            
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveChanges", "Contact")",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects),            
        success: function(result) {

      }

    });        

});
```

Controller Code:

```
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function SaveChanges(ByVal data As JsonResult) As ActionResult

   Return View()

End Function
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your posted data truly dynamic in that it could contain any combination of completely unknown properties?  Or is it posting dynamic values (or arrays of values) for known properties?

Comment: If the items you are posting are truly dynamic... completely unknown and unknowable, how do you anticipate using the values in the controller action?  How will you know what to put where?  Typically you would have an index location or parameter name to work with.

Comment: I have context from out side that gives me the info on how I will store the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say pass it as a string, that's what it is, since you're using stringify. You can then deserialize the JSON from a string in your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function to return Json instead of a view. I'm not a VB programmer but looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4049074/291687) solution, the following should help you get started:

```
Return Json(New With {Key
    .someList = resultList,
    .someInt = resultInt},
     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

You will need to modify the anonymous object to return the values needed.

Comment: The problem is that the controller method is not receiving any data.  The "data" parameter is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of someone doing something similar:
http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/02/aspnet-mvc-dynamic-json-jquery.html

The examples are in C# though.

Comment: Was article before but could not find the assembly that houses the JsonValue object in the version of .net I am using...

Comment: Using Nuget, install the "WebApi" package by Microsoft to add a reference to your poject.